# Ionic - Limit the ion-content width with max-width not set in center of the screen

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I want to fix the max-width of  in ionic, and it works fine. It limiting 1200px as `max-width` but it's not setting it in the center of the screen I tried to set `margin: auto !important` but it's not overwriting `:host{}` `margin` values if I uncheck it in host it's working fine but how to overwrite or remove `:host` CSS property?

**Applied CSS:**

```
ion-content {
  --background: #CFD8DC;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto !important;
}
```

**Below is the result:**
[image]

**Expected output:**
[image]

I tried to add `ion-row` and `ion-col` inside `ion-content` and make that row with `max-width: 1200px` work but I want the same with `ion-content`

Any help is appreciated!

Anything I am missing on any property? Guide me here I tried almost all the possible way but not overwriting the margin property.

Comment: try adding these property in to your css: 
`display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

Comment: I tried that too it's not overwriting the margin of :host that's the issue with ionic.